# Abnormal server behaviour MySql time-out

Tags: mysql, timeout

I have a development server that I use to  host a mysql database for an Asp MVC web app I'm developing.

When I work from my home, everything works fine.

I sometimes work from my parent's house, and the connection to the server is really unstable.
Half of the requests to the database are getting a MySql time-out, so it's incredibly frustrating to work.

The internet connection works perfectly well. And I'm using the same laptop.
Using TCP protocol, have a traffic inbound rule on the firewall on default port (3306)

Have you any idea why I could be having these problems ? I'm guessing there's something to configure on the server, but I don't know what..
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ISP problems, maybe your parent's ISP has an overloaded "path" to the data center.

Comment: I have no problems using remote desktop, so I was thinking this could be specific to the mysql connection, does that make any sense ?

Comment: Yeah, if you have other connections to the server which work fine, it might be an issue with DNS, possibly your parent's connection isn't resolving well. Try adding `skip-name-resolve` to your MySQL configuration.

Comment: So I added "skip-name-resolve" in the my.ini file just below [mysqld]. I then restarted mysql with the command "net stop mysql" and "net start mysql". However this has not done the trick :(

Comment: Is the server heavily loaded?

Comment: No, there's only 2 people using it and it's mostly for a few requests on MySql server. By the way, I'm specifying the IP address of the server in my connection string, so DNS should not be a problem ?

Comment: Dns is actually used on the other side, MySQL is looking at your IP, and seeing if it has a DNS entry to match it against a user in the grant table.. if that takes a while, it can cause issues with timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not really find a solution to this, thought I'd do a recap for anyone who could be having the same problem:

- To rule out ISP problems use another program to test the connection (in my case windows remote desktop)
- Try adding skip-name-resolve to your MySQL configuration (add "skip-name-resolve" in the my.ini file just below [mysqld] and restart mysql)

I ended up installing a local MySql database on my laptop, which is probably a better practice than using a shared one !